# Margin CSS not working between div's

Tags: html, css

I have two div's that I am trying to put space between `<div id="menu">` and `<div class="Content">`.

Here is a screenshot of what it currently looks like and as you can see the  image is right up against the bottom of the navigation menu.

[image: Page Screen Shot]

I have added margins to both of them, but so far nothing that I do has worked. No amount of pixels has given any space between my navigation and the page content. 
I have a margin-bottom on the `<div class="Logo">` and that worked to put space below it so I just can't seem to figure out what I cant put space below the navigation and/or above the content.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>EGLT Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css" />

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="responsivemenu.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="box-effect">
            <div class="Header">
                <div class="Logo">
                    <img src="images/EverClearLogo.png" width="306px" height="125px" alt="Company Logo" />
                </div>
                <div class="Contact-Info">
                    <a href="mailto:evercleargl@gmail.com""><img src="images/icon_Email.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="Email Ever Clear" /></a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/evercleargl"><img src="images/icon_Facebook.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="Ever Clear Facebook Page" /></a>
                    <a href="contact.html"><img src="images/icon_Phone.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="Go To Contact Us Page" /></a>
                </div>
                <div id="menu" class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='index.html' title=""><span class="icon"><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-home"></i><span></span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='about.html' title=""><span class="icon"><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-newspaper"></i><span></span>About Us</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='services.html' title=""><span class="icon"><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-hammer"></i><span></span>Services</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='gallery.html' title=""><span class="icon"><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-image"></i><span></span>Gallery</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='contact.html' title=""><span class="icon"><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-phone"></i><span></span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">
                <div class="Home-Left">
                    <img src="images/EverClearEdited.jpg" width="547px" height="315px" alt="Ever Clear Grading Landscaping Trucking" />
                </div>
                <div class="Home-Right">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Footer">
                <div class="Copyright">
                    &copy; Copyright: Jason Milam - 2015
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* SHARED STYLES */
body {
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    background-image: url("images/RedHexagons.jpg");
}

.Header {
    height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Footer {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

.box-effect {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Logo {
    width: 306px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Contact-Info {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0; 
}

.Copyright {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/* HOME PAGE STYLES */
.Content {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.Home-Left {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.Home-Right {
    width: 50%;
}

/* NAVIGATION MENU */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?8n7hjk');
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix8n7hjk') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff?8n7hjk') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?8n7hjk') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg?8n7hjk#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'icomoon';
        src: url('fonts/icomoon.svg?8n7hjk#icomoon') format('svg');

    }
}
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;

    /* Better Font Rendering */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#menu {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.icon-home:before {
    content: "\e900";
}

.icon-newspaper:before {
    content: "\e904";
}

.icon-image:before {
    content: "\e90d";
}

.icon-phone:before {
    content: "\e942";
}

.icon-hammer:before {
    content: "\e996";
}

.icon-menu:before {
    content: "\e9bd";
}

/* Global CSS for all screen sizes */
.nav {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

.nav ul {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.nav li span {
    display: block;
}

.nav a {
    display: block;
    color: rgba(249, 249, 249, .9);
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color .5s, background .5s, height .5s;
}

.nav i{
    /* Make the font smoother for Chrome */
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

/* Remove the blue Webkit background when element is tapped */
a, button {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

/* Hover effect for nav menu */
.no-touch .nav ul:hover a {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.no-touch .nav ul:hover a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.99);
}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+1) {
    background: #000000;
}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+2) {
    background: #000000;
}
.nav li:nth-child(6n+3) {
    background: #000000;
}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+4) {
    background: #000000;
}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+5) {
    background: #000000;
}

.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+1) a:hover,
.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+1) a:active,
.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+1) a:focus {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #E36220;
}

.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+2) a:hover,
.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+2) a:active,
.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+2) a:focus {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #E36220;
}

.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+3) a:hover,
.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+3) a:active,
.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+3) a:focus {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #E36220;
}

.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+4) a:hover,
.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+4) a:active,
.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+4) a:focus {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #E36220;
}

.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+5) a:hover,
.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+5) a:active,
.no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+5) a:focus {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #E36220;
}

/* Place the icon */
.icon {
    padding-top: 1.4em;
}

.icon + span {
    margin-top: 2.1em;
    transition: margin .5s;
}

/* Animating the height of the element*/
.nav a {
    height: 7em;
}

/* Making the text follow the height animation */
.no-touch .nav a:hover .icon + span {
    margin-top: 3.2em;
    transition: margin .5s;
}

/* Positioning the icons and preparing for the animation*/
.nav i {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    padding:0.4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.8em transparent;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
}   

/* Styling the toggle menu link and hiding it */
.nav .navtoogle{
    display: none;  
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.8em;
    font-family: 'Lato',Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: rgb(7, 16, 15);
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background: none;   
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navtoogle i{
    z-index:-1;
}

.icon-menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 1.6em;
}

/* RESPONSIVE STYLES */
@media (min-width: 800px) {

    /* Transforms the list into a horizontal navigation */
    .nav li {
        float: left;
        width: 16.66666666666667%;
        text-align: center;
        transition: border .5s;
    }

    .nav a {
        display: block;
        width: auto;
    }
}

/* The "tablet" and "mobile" version */
@media (max-width: 799.9px) {       

    /* Instead of adding a border, we transition the background color */
    .no-touch .nav ul a:hover,
    .no-touch .nav ul a:active,
    .no-touch .nav ul a:focus {
        background: #000000;
    }

    .nav ul li {
        transition: background 0.5s;
    }   

}

/* CSS for a 2x3 columns version */
@media (min-width: 520px) and (max-width: 799px) {

    /* Creating the 2 column layout using floating elements once again */
    .nav li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        height: 90px;
    }

    /* Adding some padding to make the elements look nicer */
    .nav a {
        padding-left: 1em;      
    }

    /* Displaying the icons on the left, and the text on the right side using inline-block */
    .nav li span, 
    .nav li span.icon {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .nav li span.icon {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .nav li .icon + span {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .icon + span {
        position: relative;
        /*top: -0.2em*/
    }

    /* Adapting the animation for smaller screens*/
    .nav li i {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8% 9%;
        border: 4px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        transition: border .5s;
    }

    /* Transition effect on the border color */
    .no-touch .nav li:hover i,
    .no-touch .nav li:active i,
    .no-touch .nav li:focus i {
        border: 4px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
}

/* Adapting the font size and width for smaller screns*/
@media (min-width: 32.5em) and (max-width: 38.688em) {

    .nav li span.icon {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .nav li .icon + span {
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 32.438em) {

    /* Unhiding the styled menu link */
    .nav .navtoogle{
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
    }

    /* Animating the height of the navigation when the button is clicked */
    /* If JavaScript is disabled, the menu stays open */
    .no-js .nav ul {
        max-height: 30em;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* When JavaScript is enabled, we hide the menu */
    .js .nav ul {
        max-height: 0em;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* Displaying the menu when the user has clicked on the button */
    .js .nav .active + ul {     
        max-height: 30em;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height .4s;
    }

    /* Adapting the layout of the menu for smaller screens */
    .nav li span {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .nav a {
        padding: 0.5em;     
    }

    .icon + span {
        margin-left: auto;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }

    .nav li {
        border-left: 8px solid #E36220;
    }

    /* make the nav bigger on touch screens */
    .touch .nav a {
        padding: 0.8em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to make a JS Fiddle of this? Would make it easier to work out the problem

Comment: I can try. I've never used JS Fiddle before.

Comment: Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y0yL6sn7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the margin-bottom is working as applied to .menu is two-fold. First, there is a height on .Header that is smaller than the content it contains.  Second, your floating all of the li elements left, thus .menu really has no height.  If you remove the height from .Header, and remove float:left from the li elements, and instead use display:inline-block on them, the margin works.

Then your li elements will need to be fixed a bit so there's not space in between them.

Comment: Or you could do as suggested in the other answer, and add a div with style clear:both after the ul, but you'll still need to get rid of the height on the .Header element

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly without having to add an empty div and your explanation is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

your `.nav li` is floated, add a `clear:both` div after your menu and it should solve the problem